# Is there any way to prevent this error in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

I'm trying to extract text from pdf file then put it in a string.

I found "pdfReader" and tried to implement it, but I always get an error. At first it begins reading the text normally then when the pdf file ends it stops and block the app.

Code:

```
var PdfReader = require("pdfreader").PdfReader;
router.get('/adminse', function(req, res, next){

aux='';
new PdfReader().parseFileItems("D:/bureau/VoguelConsulting/Backend/uploads/cv_url_CV_anglais_20191337991.pdf", function(err, item){
if (err)
          callback(err);
     else if(item==='undefined'){
        console.log('erreur');
    }
    else if(item.text) 
    {
          aux = item.text;
          console.log(' aux = ' + aux);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('working');}
    });
});
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code to the question instead of hosing it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a falsy check with the not operator (`!`), this will work with `undefined` and `null` as well:

```
else if (!item){
  console.log('erreur');
} else if(item.text) {
...
```